# Determining timestamp data from hexadecimal data

Tags: encoding, timestamp, hex

I'm trying to extract timestamp data from a hexadecimal sequence and I've narrowed down the hex data where the timestamp is hidden

I've found two dates that are off by about two minutes

```
(2012-12-01 06:00:55 -0700)
A4  01  1B  FE  36  05  88  23  E4  40  

(2012-12-01 06:02:56 -0700)
A4  01  EF  F9  AF  10  88  23  E4  40  

(2012-12-01 06:00:49 -0700)
A4  01  67  5B  A5  04  88  23  E4  40  

(2012-12-02 06:00:47 -0700)
A4  01  D6  CF  74  04  A8  23  E4  40
```

More timestamps

```
A4  01  90  A1  B2  03  C8  2E  E4  40
A4  01  22  2D  E3  03  C8  2E  E4  40  
 -0800 
E0  01  FF  15  82  03  C8  2E  E4  40
```

I'm pretty sure, based on some other data that I was able to disqualify from being the date, that it is using little endian encoding

But this is about as far as I can get. I'm using this website http://fmdiff.com/fm/timestamp.html to convert the know timestamp to some common formats, but I'm just not seeing it.

Is there any other format (probably in .net) that I can try that this info is using?

---

Solved, thanks @Markus

here's the code that converts the (LE) hex

```
#include <Debug.au3>
#include <Date.au3>

_DebugSetup("Debug")

Func GetExcelTimestamp($dec)
   $excel_time = Dec($dec,3)
   $timeinms = ($excel_time-25569)*24*3600*1000
   $sTime = _DateAdd("s", Int($timeinms / 1000), "1970/01/01 00:00:00")

   _DebugOut($dec & " - " & $sTime)
   Return $sTime
EndFunc   ;==>GetExcelTimeDate


GetExcelTimestamp("40E423880536FE1B")
GetExcelTimestamp("40E4238810AFF9EF")
GetExcelTimestamp("40E4238804A55B67")
GetExcelTimestamp("40E423A80474CFD6")
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, do you have more example dates that you can post? That way we could try to do a linear fit, which might make it more clear what you are dealing with here. Unfortunately from just those 2 numbers, I'm not seeing anything either. They should be about 121,000 ms apart, but I can't find that number in their difference...

Comment: added 2 more timestamps, I'll try to add some more with different days as well. I've also came across this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx, that's talking about `If it's a 64-bit value starting with "01" and a letter, it's probably a Win32 FILETIME. The "01A" era began in 1972` I take it that these values should be read in two bytes, with values reversed so `A4 01` would be `01 A4`. Also note the day difference (last item is 12-02 and is showing up as 23A8 instead of 2388)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the Java code that will read the dates (explanation follows):

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Convert from hex to usable date value

long temp = 0x40E423880536FE1BL; // Decode 64-bit little endian (backwards) hex
//long temp = 0x40E4238810AFF9EFL; // example 2
//long temp = 0x40E4238804A55B67L; // example 3
//long temp = 0x40E423A80474CFD6L; // example 4

double excel_time = Double.longBitsToDouble(temp); // days since 1/1/1900

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Convert to something that Java can handle and output in correct timezone

long java_time = (long) ((excel_time-25569)*24*3600*1000); // ms since 1/1/1970
Date date = new Date(java_time);

SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // don't change timezone
System.out.println(dateFormatGmt.format(date));
```

The dates are stored as days since Jan 1st, 1900 ([the way Excel stores them](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1694-how-excel-stores-date-and-time-values/)), converted to hex from a [Double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) in little endian format as you guessed correctly. The `A4 01` which you included in the beginning is probably not part of the date.

Your dates are stored in the time-zone you posted (GMT-7), not in UTC.

**Note:**

It might be that the `A4 01` **is** part of the number if it is some other floating point format, like an 80-bit extended format. But given that it is the same across your 4 examples, I rather think it's not.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Markus. I appreciate the help. I was able to get some more timestamp data, including from a different timezone, looks like that's what A4 01 waas

Comment: Hmm.... the new time-stamps don't work with my code. For them I get `2013-Mar-01 06:00:38`, `2013-Mar-01 06:00:41`, and `2013-Mar-01 06:00:36` respectively. Very strange. Are you sure those are correct? ;) Because the data format sounds very reasonable...

Comment: I think you are right, I must have matched them up wrong... I mean - you have passed the test :)

Comment: I haven't been able to get the translation to work yet, I'm using autoit, and it might take me a bit to get it converted. But looks like the date format is correct, since you're getting the right dates.

Comment: Phewwww..... ;) Good that the world still makes sense... :) I've never worked with autoit. I hope it provides you with functions to convert between Double and Binary, otherwise this might get a little bit painful. Although, since you know that you probably won't have to worry about NaN's and subnormal values, it might not be too bad. Good luck and let me know if you run into trouble with the math. I might be able to help. :)

Comment: You might be in luck! Check out the first reply to this question: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/148757-c-isam-binary-floatdouble-from-file-problem/

Comment: Ha :) , actually I was using that code, and that was causing the problems. I switched to `Dec($hex,3)` the flag `3` uses a double value

Comment: Here are the values for excel_time in order: `41244.25063657408`, `41244.25203703704`, `41244.25056712963`, `41245.250543981485`, `41334.250451388885`, `41334.25047453704`, `41334.25042824074`

Comment: Nice! :) BTW: Depending on how you need to use the date value, you might not want/need to do the java conversion. I have no idea how AutoIt stores dates, but Java's format is somewhat non-standard, so you might need to change that conversion as needed.

Comment: Good, I got it. I'll post the final code... thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No worries! It was a fun puzzle! :)